# How to use Ettercap arp spoofing to log internet traffic (how to resolve ineffective arp spoofing)?

Tags: arp-spoofing, ettercap

I want to capture all internet traffic on a small network, so I am experimenting with ARP spoofing of the default gateway but I don't see the spoofed ARP cache entries.

I am using two Linux machines on the network, one - the *attack* machine - runs `ettercap` and the other plays the role of *victim*. The third partipant is the default gateway which is a typical ADSL router. There are other devices on the network. All devices are connected over ethernet (wired).

I run `ettercap` (version 0.8.2) like this:

```
ettercap -T -j ettercap.hosts -M arp:remote -w ettercap.pcap /10.0.0.10/ //
```

where `ettercap.hosts` contains the hosts on the network (being a class A, a scan isn't practical) and the IP address is that of the default gateway.

Running `arp` on the victim shows that it has the correct MAC for the default gateway but I would expect it to show the MAC for the machine running `ettercap`. I see similar on the router: it has the correct MAC for the victim machine. I expected the arp caches to be modified to point at the attack machine.

Running `wireshark` on the victim machine shows that ARP packets are being sent by `ettercap` but they don't have any effect. For example:

```
136 13:50:12.666418095  Sony_8d:3f:5e   AsustekC_b9:59:24   ARP 60  10.0.0.10 is at 00:01:4a:8d:3f:5e
```

I presume that I misunderstand or am missing something but I am not clear what.

What is the right way to use `ettercap` to arp spoof the default gateway to log all traffic ?

Comment: Does your router have anti-ARP spoofing defenses enabled?

Comment: In order to tell the victim host that now we (our MAC address) are the one belonging to the IP of the gateway enter the following command:
`arpspoof -t victim gateway`
In a seperate shell we start the matching command to fool gateway to belive we are victim.
`arpspoof -t gateway victim`
Don't forget to enable IP forwarding on your host so the traffic goes through your host. Otherwise victim will loose connectivity.
`echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`
 ..watch all the traffic between the victim host and the outside network going through your machine
`tcpdump host victim and not arp`

Comment: with the tool `arpwatch` you can verify that it works. 

in case it doesn't, i suspect your router prohibits it somehow (many new do so), as mentioned by @MaximilianGerhardt ... you can probably change that in the router-settings.

Comment: Ok, so using `arpspoof` I can see the expected arp change on the victim. I can also see it reset pretty much straight away. The change does not effect on the router at all. I guess the router must have anti-ARP spoofing defenses on it. I don't know - I need to see what I can find from its crap documentation (its a thomson speedtouch tg585). Also, `arpwatch` didn't work for me `bad interface enp4s0: no IPv4 address assigned` I don't know if that's because its bridged.